# React BrightCove Player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, brightcove

I am using react Brightcove Player. Everything is working fine but I am getting console message -
**VM37307 index.min.js:1 VIDEOJS: WARN: Calling addRemoteTextTrack without explicitly setting the "manualCleanup" parameter to `true` is deprecated and default to `false` in future version of video.js**

Any idea, How to resolve this Warning, I tried multiple things but no Luck.